# How does aws instance sync time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have not enabled NTP on my machine(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html); just timezone settings are made.

When I start a new instance from an image, how does it get its time setting, and who is taking care of it for me?

Answer (score 3):

When a VM powers up, it generally gets the time from a physical host. So the time may be reasonably accurate (assuming Amazon keeps the time accurate on their hosts).  But VM time tends to drift (minutes per day), unless you have NTP or a similar synchronization method in place.

Comment: Yes, this sound correct. Almost forgot about it. Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 2):

"On Amazon Linux 2, the default chrony configuration is already set up to use the Amazon Time Sync Service IP address."

For other instances it will take the value from the VPC defualts. For an instance in a Centos box you can check the settings in /etc/ntp.conf

Comment: I'm using ubuntu node and it doesn't have `/etc/ntp.conf ` file.

Comment: On Ubuntu the default time service is `systemd-timesyncd` or `chronyd` for AWS cloud pre-built instances.